# I have .net app built on .net framework 4.6.2. What may be the reason that my http request gets failed due to SSL errors?

Tags: .net, api, http, ssl, tls1.2

So my .net app makes API calls to my server that supports TLS version 1.3.My app works smoothly in most environments but in windows 7, the Httprequests to the API server gets failed due to SSL errors like listed below.

```
1.InnerException: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
2.The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
```

Note: I can access the API server via browser without any certificate trust issues.Also I have added all the Security Protocols in the ServicePointManager.

Comment: Purely a guess, AFAIK .Net 4.6.2 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol only supports up to TLS 1.2.  You'll probably need to switch to 4.7 if you're enforcing the use of TLS1.3 on the server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.6&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but any reason why this occurs in Windows 7, does upgrading my .net framework works in Windows 7 also?

Comment: Honestly, dont know, but I doubt it.  Windows 7 is no longer supported, and TLS 1.3 was only just added to Windows 10.  I wouldn't say never, but I wouldn't hold my breath either.  Any reason not to allow the use of TLS1.2?

Comment: So is it possible to connect to an API server that has SSL certificate with TLS 1.3 from any machine that would support TLS1.2?